# Laravel - Insert & delete rows upon updating

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many

I have one-to-many Model relationship. While creating a new record, I can save as many rows as I want. But I want to add new row or delete saved row after **Update** operation. How would I do it?

**Item Model**

```php
public function models() {
    return $this->hasMany(Model::class, 'item_id');
}
```

**Model Model**

```php
public function model()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'item_id');
}
```

**Controller**

*Store*

```php
public function store(Request $request, Item $item)
 {
  $item = new Item;
    $item->title = request('title');

    if($item->save())
      {
       for ($i=0; $i < count(request('model_name')); ++$i) 
        {
        $model = new Model;
        $model->name = request('name')[$i];
        $model->price = request('price')[$i];
      }
   return redirect()->back();
 }
```

*Update*

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id){
$item = Item::findOrFail($id);
$data = $request->all()
$models = Model::with(['model'])->where('item_id', $item->id)->get();
  $i=0;   
  foreach($models as $new_model)
    {
      if (isset($model_name[$i])){
           $new_model->sku = request('name')[$i];
           $new_model->price= request('price')[$i];
           $++i;
         $shnp->models()->save($new_model);
       }
    }
    $item->update($data);
  }
```

**Edit Form**

[image: Edit Form]

**Database Table**

[image: Item - Model]

Comment: Can you explain more what you want exactly?

Comment: I want a new row be inserted if I clicked ``Add Item`` button on form or delete the corresponding row if I clicked Delete button & ``Update`` button. Now I can't add or delete rows while updating.

Comment: [Check this link](https://jmkleger.com/post/ajax-crud-for-laravel-5-4) Hope this will give you the idea to work with ajax.

Comment: I didn;t get the exact solution, but it means I need go for AJAX approach to achieve this?

Comment: Yes definitely.

Comment: I am new to AJAX. Is there any example/solution that does the exact what I want?

Comment: My suggestion would be use separate update and delete button for each `Model` and create route and method for the `Model` update and delete.

Comment: As the model `Model` is an entity and your edit or delete doesn't have any relation with the model `Item` you should edit single `Model`.